# Custom navigation in Phonejs

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, cordova, phonejs

I am trying to create mobile application using [Phonejs](http://phonejs.devexpress.com). So far things are working. But now I need to implement authorization in mobile application. So, based on User rights navigation menu will be displayed. So, as per documentation I can give navigation menu once in the starting of the application. At the time of initializing the application. But now I can't find a way to access it or even a documentation on it.

Either I just need to disable few menu based on user role or if I can remove it, that will be even better. I am using simple layout; the predefined one.

Please let me know if any further details is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide navigation menu item by:

```
MyApplication.app.navigation[0].option('visible', false);
```

See [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q562550)..